# Usually AC quantities have the x-axis as time, but phase shifts are done in angles. How is there not a unit conflict?

Tags: ac, phase, phase-shift, circuits, sinusoidal

This feels like a very specific and stupid question, but I have studied AC circuits for a while already. I just didn't think about it that much, but why is it established that the x-axis we use for graphs is time but we get to be able to shift the sinusoid by the x-axis in terms of an angle? I mean, they really aren't the same units. Time is in terms of seconds commonly and angles in degrees or radians. Why does it work? How do they coexist, being able to read phase shifts and measure periods using the same axis?

Comment: One cycle is 360 degrees.  For a given frequency, those 360 degrees are the same time period as \$\frac{1}{f}\$.

Comment: Without units, all sin waves are alike, so degrees, radians or time are used as required.

Comment: Time on axis X is absolute value but angle is relative. Converting between them includes period or frequency.

Comment: \$\theta = f \times t\$

Comment: \$ \theta = \omega t \$